# Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/') connect False

Tags: javascript

```
async function loadWeb3() {
    const web3 =  new  Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/');
    console.log(web3);
}
```

Comment: but wrong connection

Comment: {
    "withCredentials": false,
    "timeout": 0,
    "connected": false,
    "host": "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/",
    "httpsAgent": {}
}

Comment: This question only includes code, please add some more details for example what troubles you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html)

```
async function loadWeb3() { 
 const web3 =  = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'));
}
```